What does "Function Resource" above my toolbar mean, and how do I get rid of it?
I am a bit lost probably. I dont know how I activated it but this appeared in my notebook. This was not above my toolbar for the most time I was working on the Notebook, which was quite a while. The bar just suddenly appeared. There is nothing unusual in my Code, I think I triggered some hidden setting.

I know how Resource functions work and I imported one, but I did not open its definition or something like that. Also I am not trying to define a new Resource function. (At least I am not aware of it).
I also did not change anything in my Code, this just appeared.
Can anyone quickly help me with this ahah, i did not find much useful info on google/this forum.

Please show your code.

I added some context to my question, I am sorry, I think it was not really well formulated before. My Notebook is probably at least 50 pages long, in the Code I was working on, when the bar appeared there is no mention of any Resource Function.

To clarify, is it just in one notebook or all notebooks?  If you create a new notebook with Cntrl-N (or Cmd-N) does it have this toolbar?

Just in this one notebook :/ So it is not a common issue then? I can still run the notebook so it is not a big problem, i thought this is an easy fix I just dont know yet haha

I can crtl A the code into a blank notebook as a last resort, i was just hoping to learn sth new.

Looks like you were playing with the Stylesheet menu.  Try Format > Stylesheet > Default. The one you seem to have looks like Format > Stylesheet > Wolfram > FunctionResourceDocumentationStyles.

Indeed, this fixed it. Thanks a lot.
